# Importar modulos en JavaScript

Tags: javascript

Estoy intentando importar un modulo en JavaScript. En `python`, pues es sencillo, simplemente importas lo que deseas con `import`.

En `javascript` por lo visto también parece sencillo. En mi caso, estoy intentando implementar el ejemplo que sale en [Using JavaScript code modules](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/JavaScript_code_modules/Using)

Sin embargo, me aparece este error en google chrome `Uncaught ReferenceError: Components is not defined`. ¿Que estaré haciendo mal?

### my_module.jsm

```
var EXPORTED_SYMBOLS = ["foo", "bar"];

function foo() {
  return "foo";
}

var bar = {
  name : "bar",
  size : 3
};

var dummy = "dummy";
```

### test.js

```
Components.utils.import("resource://my_module.jsm");

alert(foo());         // displays "foo"
alert(bar.size + 3);  // displays "6"
alert(dummy);         // displays "dummy is not defined" because 'dummy' was not exported from the module
```

### test.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title></title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>hola</h1>
    <script src="test.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: ¿Esto es como parte de un plugin/extensión?

Comment: Se supondría que no, debería estar en la librería estándar.

Comment: `Components` no es estándar. Así se indica en la propia [página de Mozilla](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Tech/XPCOM/Language_Bindings/Components_object), donde también se recomienda no usarlo en desarrollo web normal

Comment: Quizás te pueda interesar esta otra [pregunta en StackOverflow en español](http://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/1366/c%C3%B3mo-incluir-un-archivo-javascript-a-otro-archivo-javascript-sin-utilizar-jquer/). Trata de incluir modulos/archivos JS desde otros archivos JS.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Components` no es estándar y su uso en desarrollo web no está recomendado según el sitio de Mozilla Developer Network (MDN).

Traducción de la página sobre el objeto [`Components` en MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Tech/XPCOM/Language_Bindings/Components_object):

> No estándar
>
> Este característica no es estándar y no está en planes de que sea estándar. No usar en páginas web en producción: no funcionará para todos los usuarios. Puede haber también numerosas incompatibilidades y su comportamiento puede cambiar en el futuro.
>
> Atención:
>
> Este objeto no está diseñado para correr con privilegios chrome. Exponer este objeto a la web fue un error. Si usas este objeto en tu sitio web, ¡tu página puede romperse en cualquier momento! En las versiones actuales de Firefox sólo unas cuantas interfaces requeridas para su funcionamiento están activas. ¡No uses `Components`!

Answer (score 4):

Olvídate de `Components`, no es estándar, pero te propongo una alternativa donde **SI** es posible *importar* otro archivo JavaScript usando medios estándar, este [truco](https://stackoverflow.com/a/950146/2573335) que aprendí en SO original:

```
// declaras un función que agregue el script a la cabecera del HTML
// y te notifique cuando el archivo termino de cargarse
function import(url, callback)
{
    var head = document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0];
    var script = document.createElement('script');
    script.type = 'text/javascript';
    script.src = url;
    // compatibilidad cross browser 
    script.onreadystatechange = callback;
    script.onload = callback;
    head.appendChild(script);
}

// ... así se usa

import("url/del/archivo.js", function() {
  // aqui ya se cargo el script, de forma global, como cualquier otro.
});
```

Casi tan fácil como un import en `pyton`, solo que es asincronico :P

Por cierto, también tienes a `jQuery.getScript()`, o incluso usando `Ajax` para cargar código JavaScript.

Hay formas que funcionan en todos los navegadores.

Por cierto, [Components](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Tech/XPCOM/Language_Bindings/Components.utils) no va a funcionar en Chrome ni en otros navegadores, no es parte del [estándar vigente](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/index.html) (Living standard).

Eso esta hecho para [`jsm`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/JavaScript_code_modules/Using), que es javascript modular, una pieza propia de Gecko para extender Firefox.

Comment: Pero esto no seria algo como lo mismo que `<script src="url/del/archivo.js"></script>`? y por otro lado, como haría si solo quiero importar una variable o función especifica del modulo?

Comment: @JavierCárdenas esto te permite cargar un javascript desde otro javascript, lo que tu dices es cargar un javascript desde html y por otro lado, cualquier variable "global" (que este declarada en el cuerpo del archivo ej: `var nombreVar = 1;`) sera accesible desde todos los scripts cargados, son globales.

Answer (score 1):

`Components` no es estándar, sin embargo podrías hacer uso de `ES6` y `Babel + Webpack` para realizar los `imports`.