# Enviar variables desde formulario con innerHTML a un archivo javascript

Tags: javascript

Necesito enviar el contenido del formulario "form4" hacia form4.js para que realice otras operaciones de carga en la base de datos de Firebase ¿Cómo enviar la información que sale del "form4", que ha sido creado con innerHTML en el archivo form3.js, hacia el archivo form4.js?

El formulario que tiene el problema lo tengo en el archivo form3.js

No sé si innerHTML no permite la etiqueta , o si es mejor importar el form4.js.
Necesito ayuda gracias.

ARCHIVO form3.js

```
//******enviar datos del formulario "form4" a form4.js **********//
            resultado.innerHTML +=`
                     <form id="form4">
                       <div class="form-group">
                         <div class="col-md-6 mb-3">
                           <label for="name-users">Nombre</label>
                           <input type="text" class="form-control is-valid" id="name-users"   >
                           <div class="valid-feedback">
                             * este campo es obligatorio
                           </div>
                         </div>
                

     <div class="col-md-6 mb-3">
                       <label for="id-users">No. identificación del usuario</label>
                       <input type="text" class="form-control " id="id-users" required >
                       <div class="valid-feedback">             
                       </div>
                     </div>
                     
                     <div class="col-md-6 mb-3">
                       <label for="email-users">Email</label>
                       <input type="email" class="form-control is-valid" id="email-users"  >
                       <div class="valid-feedback">
                         * este campo es obligatorio
                       </div>
                     </div>
                     
                   <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit">REGISTRAR</button>
                 </form>
             
                 <script src="form4.js"></script>
          
        `;
    });
})
.catch(function(error) {
    console.log("Error getting documents: ", error);
});
//******fin de enviar datos del formulario "form4" a form4.js **********//
```

ARCHIVO form4.js

```
const form4 = document.getElementById("form4");

form4.addEventListener("submit", async (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    const nameUsers = form4 ["name-users"];
    const idUsers = form4 ["id-users"];
    const emailUsers = form4 ["email-users"];
       
})
```

Comment: Pero en este caso porque quisieras enviar esta informacion que tienes en form3.js a form4.js?, porque lo haz dividido de esa manera?, estas queriendo usar form4.js como backend?, si ese es el caso porque no veo la etiqueta `nodeJS` en tu pregunta?, si ese no es el caso y solo quieres pasar informacion y seguir usando javascript del lado del cliente, porque lo divides en dos archivos?, en este caso tiene sentido de que solo sea un archivo, ya que no necesitas dos archivos para pasar esa informacion a firebase, solo necesitas uno.

Comment: Por cierto... `innerHTML` lo que hace es añadir contenido HTML a la pagina, mas no "envia" datos, `innerHTML` no es la forma de lograr tu cometido.

Comment: El script no se va a cargar agregándolo con _elemento.innerHTML_, tal vez [esta respuesta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/3708/importar-modulos-en-javascript/3710#3710) te pueda ser útil.

Comment: muchas gracias por sus respuestas, me han dado luces

Answer (score 0):

Voy a asumir que lo que deseas hacer es simplemente para dividir de mejor manera la informacion, y hacer los procesos necesarios en archivos separados, lo cual de todas maneras te digo que hagas **bajo tu propio riezgo**,  puesto que recordemos que el **backend** es algo fundamental en una aplicacion web o simplemente una web.

El backend es el encargado de realizar comprobaciones y de corroborar, almacenar y tramitar informacion entre el cliente, el servidor o ambos.

Tambien recordemos que lo mejor seria siempre hacer comprobaciones tanto del lado del **cliente como del lado del servidor**, esto mas que todo si se trata de información sensible o que pueda dar lugar a bugs si se inserta de manera inadecuada.

En tu caso solo nos muestras la etiqueta `"javascript"`, javascript **puro** solo es usado en el lado del cliente, por lo que tenemos que asumir que esa informacion que quieres enviar es enrealidad informacion no-sensible y que por tanto no va a comprometer la seguridad del usuario.

**Si este no es el caso no prosigas con esta solucion, pues haras mas daño que bien.**

En su lugar deberas optar por usar un backend como por ejemplo `nodeJS`, para procesar esta informacion y mandarla a `firebase` o tratarla etc.

**En caso de que la informacion a enviar solamente sea de prueba o sea informacion irrelevante para el usuario, puedes proseguir.**

Tu problema es basicamente:

Como envio informacion de un archivo `"A"` a un archivo `"B"`, en este caso aparentemente lo que quieres no es enviar informacion a otra pagina, si no a otro archivo. para hacer esto lo que considero mejor es usar modulos de **ES6**.

Te voy a poner un ejemplo sencillo:

```js
//Archivo form3.js
import { receiver } from "./js/form4.js";

window.onload = ()=>{
  //Para realizar acciones solo cuando la pagina se cargue...
  
  //Enviaremos el contenido de esta constante a form4.js:
  const numero = 4;
  receiver(numero);
}


//Archivo form4.js:
export function receiver(info){
  //Aqui realizaremos alguna accion en el archivo cuando la funcion sea ejecutada.
  logWhenReceived(info);
}

function logWhenReceived(info){
  console.log("Se recibio en el archivo form4.js la siguiente informacion:" + info);
}
```

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Titulo de la pagina</title>
    <script type = "module" src = "/js/form3.js"></script> <!-- OJO AQUI CON EL ATRIBUTO TYPE -->
  </head>
  
  <body>
  </body>
</html>
```

Basicamente estamos usando una funcion que hace parte del archivo `form4.js` en el archivo `form3.js` para asi poder hacer uso de la informacion que necesitemos del archivo `form3.js` en cualquier momento dado en `form4.js`.

**Nota**: pofavor leer los comentarios dejados en el codigo, ademas hay ciertas cosas que hay que tener en cuenta a la hora de usar modulos de **ES6**, pues si ejecutas el codigo sin mas no te va a funcionar, habra que tener en cuenta entonces los siguientes aspectos:

- Los modulos de `ES6` solo funcionaran ejecutandolos mediante un servidor (puede ser un servidor local). por ejemplo `http-server` de `npm` o `xampp`.
- Para que las sentencias `import` y `export` sean validas el script principal debe estar declarado como tipo `module`.
- Recuerda anadir la extension `.js` al final de la importacion, a vecez visual studio code lo hace erroneamente.
- Las importaciones deben llevar como minimo 1 punto o 2 (dependiendo de la ruta) para poder ser validas, por lo que la ruta `"/js/script.js"` **NO** es valida, pero `"./js/script.js"` **SI** es valido.

Comment: que buena respuesta me has dado, muchas gracias amigo

Comment: Hola, de nada amigo, aqui para servir, recuerda que si la respuesta te ha ayudado, me ayudarias bastante si das la respuesta como aceptada dandole al boton que parece un chulo.