# ¿Como importar módulos en javascript utilizando ES6 y Babel.js?

Tags: javascript, babeljs

Leyendo la respuesta https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/1371/353 vi como es posible importar modulos utilizando `ES6`.

Sin embargo, de acuerdo a lo que he leído, aún no esta implementado en los navegadores y por eso es necesario utilizar un transpiler como `Babel.js`.

Mi problema ahora es que estoy probando un ejemplo y aún me aparece este error `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token import` a pesar de haber ejecutado `npm run build` tal como aparece en la documentación [Babel CLI docs](https://babeljs.io/docs/setup/#babel_cli) y de instalar el plugin de AMD [AMD plugin](http://babeljs.io/docs/plugins/transform-es2015-modules-amd/)

Así se ve el directorio del ejemplo:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y este es el código:

### src/functions.js

```
export function sum (a, b) {
  return a + b
}
```

### src/main.js

```
'use strict'
import {sum} from 'functions'
let a = 10
let b = 5
console.log(sum(a, b))
```

### dist/main.js

```
'use strict';

import { sum } from 'functions';
let a = 10;
let b = 5;
console.log(sum(a, b));
```

### dist/main.js

```
export function sum(a, b) {
  return a + b;
}
```

### index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>ES6 Getting Started</title>
    <meta name="description" content="An example of how to use ES6">
  </head>
  <body>
    <p>
      View the console
    </p>
    <script src="dist/main.js">
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

### package.json

```
{
  "name": "my-project",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "build": "babel src -d dist"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-cli": "^6.4.5"
  }
}
```

Comment: Échale un vistazo a este artículo [ES6 In Depth: Using ES6 today with Babel and Broccoli](https://hacks.mozilla.org/2015/06/es6-in-depth-babel-and-broccoli/) yo uso módulos ES6 pero con TypeScript compilado a ES5 y para la carga Systemjs

Comment: ¿Te muestra algún error al hacer el build con babel? ¿podrías incluir el contenido archivo compilado? Creo que te está llegando el `import` al navegador y este no lo reconoce. Por cierto, el `import'  debería ser como dice @Wilfredo-P en su respuesta

Comment: @rsciriano ya incluí los archivos compilados. No me muestra error o warning al hacer build con babel.

Comment: @rsciriano lo intentaré ver más tarde. Es que son tantas cosas que aparecen nuevas que no se donde empezar: que el babel, el browserify, el webpack. el brocoli, el angular, el cli, el ember, y etc etc etc y yo lo único que quiero por ahora es hacer un import....

Comment: Yo estuve dándole vueltas al esto de los módulos `ES6` pero con `TypeScript` y mi solución final es con `WebPack` miraré este artículo ["TypeScript and webpack"](http://www.jbrantly.com/typescript-and-webpack/). `Babel` me parece mas complicado y no conseguí llegar a lo que quería (y para la compilación ya tengo a `TypeScript`)

Comment: @rsciriano Yo creo que me quedo con Typescript a nivel de los docs, creo que esta mejor :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Creo que no te está funcionando el plugin que convierte los módulos `ES6` en módulos `AMD`

Aseguraré que en el archivo `.babelrc` está incluido el plugin y has instalado el paquete npm

```
{
    "plugins": ["transform-es2015-modules-amd"]
}
```

Después de hacer esto, al compilar con `babel`, los archivos resultantes deberían ser así:

**dist/main.js**

```
define(['functions'], function (_functions) {
'use strict';

let a = 10;
let b = 5;
console.log((0, _functions.sum)(a, b));
});
```

**dist/functions.js**

```
define(["exports"], function (exports) {
"use strict";

Object.defineProperty(exports, "__esModule", {
    value: true
});
exports.sum = sum;

function sum(a, b) {
    return a + b;
}
});
```

Por último, para cargar los módulos AMD, tienes que usar `requirejs`, el archivo **index.html** quedaría así

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>ES6 Getting Started</title>
    <meta name="description" content="An example of how to use ES6">
  </head>
  <body>
    <p>
      View the console
    </p>
    <script data-main="dist/main" src="libs/require.js">
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Tengo que descargar `require.js`, crear una carpeta `libs` y ubicarlo ahí, cierto?

Comment: Exacto @JavierCárdenas

Comment: Perfecto, me funcionó al fin! Mi duda ahora es porque se usa `data-main`

Comment: @JavierCárdenas  en `data-main` se establece el módulo principal, lo puede ver [aquí](http://requirejs.org/docs/api.html#data-main), en la documentación de `requirejs`. Se podría usar de otra manera pero esa es la mas **basica**. También podrías usar otras librerías de carga de módulos como `systemjs` que admite módulos en varios formatos