# ¿Como veo una variable desde otro script?

Tags: javascript, jquery

La hago corta. Tengo ciertas variables en **script1** recogidas de **html1**, y quiero ver algunas desde **script2** cuando cargue **html2**. 
Intenté usando variables globales, pero no lo consigo. Las veo vacías desde **script2**. Supongo que se debe a una cuestión de scope que yo no se.

El usuario pasa de **html1** a **html2** mediante un boton. La variable de la que hablo es, en concreto, una opcion de un dropdown que capturo mediante JQuery y se guarda en una variable global. **html1** y **html2** tienen cada uno su script. Lo que yo quiero hacer es cargar **html2** y mostrar la opcion que eligió el usuario en dicho dropdown ubicado en **html1**.

He intentado haciendo esto:

```
variableGlobal = funcionXqueRetornaOpciondeDropdown;
```

y después usar la misma variable en **script2**, pero la veo undefined. (Notese que hago referencia a los dos scripts en **html2** al final del body)

**script1**

```js
$(function(){
dropdownCaptura = function (dropdown, boton) {
        dropdown.on('click', 'li', function () {
            ciudad = $(this).text();
            if (boton.hasClass("btn-danger")) {
                boton.switchClass("btn-danger", "btn-primary", 0);
                $("#divDanger").fadeOut();
            }
            boton.html(ciudad);
            return ciudad;
        });
    };
});
ciudadOrigen = dropdownCaptura(dropdownOrigen1, btnDropdownOrigen1);
```

*La captura del Dropdown funciona.*

**script2**

```js
$(function(){
    var ciudad = ciudadOrigen;
    console.log(ciudad);
});
```

Comment: Bienvenido a [Stack Overflow en Español](http://es.stackoverflow.com/tour), 
puede tratar de mejorar su pregunta mirando este [enlace](http://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), 
es posible que su pregunta sea cerrada o puesta en espera no se lo tome a mal, 
para mas información consulte el siguiente [enlace](http://es.stackoverflow.com/help/closed-questions). 
Saludos

Comment: revisa este http://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/1366/c%C3%B3mo-incluir-un-archivo-javascript-a-otro-archivo-javascript-sin-utilizar-jquer

Comment: Hola @Aaren. ¡Bienvenido a [es.so]! No me queda claro. ¿Son páginas diferentes, y desde html1 se va a html2 haciendo click en un enlace/llenando un formulario... cómo? Además, ¿cómo se calculan esas variables en script1? ¿Dependen del contenido o lo que el usuario haya completado en html1, o es simplemente un valor fijo que se podría calcular nuevamente en html2? Quizás te sea útil realizar el [tour] y leer [ask].

Comment: Quizá se me fue la mano con el resumen. Ahora añado mas info.

Comment: Y si agregas el script queda mucho mas claro. [Cómo crear un ejemplo mínimo, completo y verificable](http://es.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Agrego entonces

Answer (score 0):

Estimado, en este caso te sugiero utilizar el local Storage que traen todos los navegadores de internet, ejemplo, Mozilla o Chrome. Abajo te dejo un ejemplo.

[Como usar el localStorage](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_webstorage.asp)

Espero te sea de utilidad.

Comment: Estoy intentandolo de esta forma ahora mismo.

Comment: Excelente. Espero que tengas buenos resultados!

Comment: Pude solucionarlo usando sessionStorage : )
Muchas gracias Alejandro!

Comment: Buenísimo!  el sessionStorage es muy buena opción en estos casos!

Answer (score 0):

Las variables que declaras en javascript pueden tener diferentes ámbitos,
estas pueden ser globales o locales, que declares una variable global no quiere
decir que se pueda acceder a esta desde otro script, acceder a una variable declarada en otro script es imposible, pero puedes utilizar query string para pasar datos de una pestaña a otra la forma de usarlo seria la siguiente:

```
$(function(){
dropdownCaptura = function (dropdown, boton) {
        dropdown.on('click', 'li', function () {
            ciudad = $(this).text();
            if (boton.hasClass("btn-danger")) {
                boton.switchClass("btn-danger", "btn-primary", 0);
                $("#divDanger").fadeOut();
            }
            boton.html(ciudad);
            return ciudad;
        });
    };
});

ciudadOrigen = dropdownCaptura(dropdownOrigen1, btnDropdownOrigen1);
window.open('html2.html?ciudadOrigen='+ciudadOrigen , '_blank');
```

y para obtener el valor de la variable en html2 usarias el siguiente código

```
var urlParams = new URLSearchParams(window.location.search);
let ciudadOrigen = "";
if (urlParams.has("ciudadOrigen")) {
     ciudadOrigen = setSearchPanel(urlParams.get('ciudadOrigen'));
}
```