# ¿Por qué una función un archivo JS no es accesible desde otro archivo?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Hice dos archivos en mi sitio web `default.js` y `resources.js`.
En `default.js` hice la función `updateDatabase()` y tengo que llamarla en `resources.js`.

Los archivos los puse de la siguiente forma dentro del html:

```
<body>
<!-- Resto del codigo -->
<script src="js/default.js"></script>
<script src="js/resources.js"></script>
</body>
```

En `default.js`:

```
$(document).ready(function(){    
    function updateDatabase(){
        $.ajax({
            url: 'database.php',
            type: 'POST',
            data: {
                'action': 'get'
            },
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function(){
                alert('HECHO');
            }
        });
    }
});
```

En `resources.js`:

```
$(document).ready(function(){    
    $('#update-btn').click(function(){
        updateDatabase();
    });
});
```

Sin embargo cada vez que intento llamar a la función `updateDatabase()` desde `resources.js` la consola dice que la función no está definida.

Comment: Hola Juanky, ¿puedes incluir el código de ambos archivos?

Comment: Por supuesto, ahora actualizo la pregunta.

Comment: Posible duplicado de [¿Cómo incluir un archivo JavaScript a otro archivo Javascript sin utilizar JQuery?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/1366/c%c3%b3mo-incluir-un-archivo-javascript-a-otro-archivo-javascript-sin-utilizar-jquer)

Comment: ¿Has importado JQuery?

Comment: Por supuesto, en `resources.js` utilizo un selector de JQuery

Comment: Y si la funcion la pones dentro del archivo default.js

Comment: Lamentablemente, debido a la estructura de mi proyecto, no puedo hacer eso. Si no, ya lo hubiese hecho.

Comment: ¿Ese es todo el código de `default.js`?  Estás seguro que `updateDatabase` no está dentro de otra función con lo cual su ámbito ya no sería global

Comment: Está dentro del `$(document).ready()`

Comment: Es es el problema, quítalo de ahí

Comment: Esa era la solución, muchas gracias @CarlosMuñoz

Comment: Por favor edita la pregunta con el código completo para poder generalizarla y así poder ayudar a mas usuarios

Answer (score 2, accepted):

La función `updateDatabase` debe ser global al archivo `default.js` es decir no estar incluida dentro de otra función ya que esto haría que se solo local a la función donde está declarada y por lo tanto no ser accesible desde afuera

En tu caso debes sacar la función afuera del `$(document).ready() {...}`

#### default.js

```
function updateDatabase() {
    $.ajax({
        url: 'database.php',
        type: 'POST',
        data: {
            'action': 'get'
        },
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function() {
            alert('HECHO');
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Muchas gracias por todo, pensé que era necesario meter todo dentro del `$(document).ready()`

Answer (score -1):

Prueba cambiando la definición en `default.js`:

```
var updateDatabase = function(){ // Solo esta línea
    $.ajax({
        url: 'database.php',
        type: 'POST',
        data: {
            'action': 'get'
        },
        dataType: 'json',
        success:{
            alert('HECHO');
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Me da un error, `updateDatabase is not a function`

Comment: Lo siento, mi error, si funciona en el mismo archivo, pero no en el otro.