# Cómo importar algún archivo .js?

Tags: javascript

Como puedo exportar en Javascript(frontend) otro archivo js, por ejemplo jquery , desde el mismo archivo .js ?

Intente esto:

```js
import "jquery.js";
```

Pero el error fué:

***Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token import***

*Por qué el error? y como debería ser?*

Comment: Posible duplicado de [¿Cómo incluir un archivo JavaScript a otro archivo Javascript sin utilizar JQuery?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/1366/c%c3%b3mo-incluir-un-archivo-javascript-a-otro-archivo-javascript-sin-utilizar-jquer) Entiendo que teniendo la etiqueta solo de javascript la respuesta tenga unicamente javascript.

Comment: @GDP No es un duplicado, una cosa es añadir un tag script dinámicamente y otra es usar módulos de ES6, son conceptos distintos

Comment: A mí me parece un duplicado. La respuesta aceptada en la otra pregunta es precisamente usando módulos de ES6, y otras respuestas incluyen alternativas para añadir scripts dinámicamente.

Answer (score 2):

Buenas, las versiones antiguas de JavaScript no lo soportan, pero con los módulos del ES6 se puede hacer algo parecido.

Crearías una función con la palabra export, para luego desde otro archivo js poder importarla. (Así es como funciona Angular 2/4 por ejemplo):

```
// module.js
export function hello() {
  return "Hello";
}

// main.js
import {hello} from 'module'; // or './module'
let val = hello(); // val is "Hello";
```

Esta información la he sacado del SO en inglés, aquí tienes un enlace por si quieres leer más al detalle: [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/950087/how-do-i-include-a-javascript-file-in-another-javascript-file)

Espero haberte sido de ayuda, saludos!!