# Distribuir el codigo jQuery en varios .js

Tags: javascript, jquery, rendimiento

En referencia a esta pregunta:

[¿Cómo incluir un archivo JavaScript a otro archivo Javascript sin utilizar JQuery?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/1366/c%C3%B3mo-incluir-un-archivo-javascript-a-otro-archivo-javascript-sin-utilizar-jquer)

Tengo un js de código jQuery muy grande, entonces, por tener todo un poco más ordenado se me ha ocurrido crear varios js y cargarlos todos en un js que sería al que se llama en el index.

Imagino que la carga siempre sera mayor que si todo esta en un único archivo. Pero no siempre lo que prima es la carga si no el tener el código lo más pulido y ordenado. Siempre y cuando sea algo asumible y que verdaderamente no afecte en consideración a la carga de la página.

Una vez dicho esto ¿Cual es la mejor opción? cargar esos scripts con jQuery o usar JavaScript puro. En cuanto a rendimiento. Gracias

Saludos

Comment: En rendimiento mientras menos librerías mejor pero jquery es casi imprescindible, ademas lo mejos es tener un solo js en sentido de rendimiento. Yo en desarrollo tengo varios js pero en producción lo subo unidos para aumentar la velocidad de carga.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

En cuanto a rendimiento: VanillaJS es mejor, de hecho luego de la última versión de ECMAScript que salió, programar en JQuery casi no tiene sentido, pues JSvanilla ha mejorado enormemente su sintaxis para hacerla más "amigable". Si quieres mi consejo, usa Vanilla si trabajas solo, pone muchos menos trabas y límites a la hora de desarrollar. Si es para encontrar trabajo, aprende jQuery, pero aprendelo cuando ya domines vanilla al revés y al derecho.

Para mejorar el rendimiento, debes usar minificadores de código, como Webpack, Gulp, Laravel-Mix, etc.

Y sobre "cómo guardarlos" depende de la plataforma que uses. La gran mayoría guarda en la carpeta assets las dependencias de código del front, y las va dividiendo por cada vista, luego en el controlador que carga las dependencias de cada vista le vas diciendo qué módulos cargar. Lo mismo con el CSS. No tiene sentido que cargues el CDN completo de jQuery para toda la página, si bien es una práctica común hoy en día, lo óptimo es definir a cada ruta la carga de elementos que le corresponden.

Answer (score 1):

Podrías hacer algo así:

```js
let nuevoScript = document.createElement('script');
nuevoScript.setAttribute("src", "el/otro/script.js");
document.body.appendChild(nuevoScript);
```

En lo que concierne lo del rendimiento de tener un solo script, las cosas parece que han cambiado. Por favor abre css-tricks.com en view-source y mira cuantos elementos script tienen.

Este es un enlace a una pregunta similar hecha en Stack Overflow en inglés: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4634644/how-to-include-js-file-in-another-js-file#4634669