# Obtener el valor retornado de una función jQuery de un archivo externo

Tags: javascript, jquery

Tengo la siguiente función en un archivo externo llamado `datepicker_range.js` (también adjunto su correspondiente `html`).

```js
$(function() {
  var dateFormat = "mm/dd/yy";
  var from = $("#from").datepicker({
      defaultDate: "+1w",
      changeMonth: true,
      numberOfMonths: 1
    })
    .on("change", function() {
      to.datepicker("option", "minDate", getDate(this));
    }),
    to = $("#to").datepicker({
      defaultDate: "+1w",
      changeMonth: true,
      numberOfMonths: 1
    })
    .on("change", function() {
      from.datepicker("option", "maxDate", getDate(this));
    });

  // Función que obtiene las fechas selccionadas
  function getDate(element) {
    var date;
    try {
      date = $.datepicker.parseDate(dateFormat, element.value);
    } catch (error) {
      date = null;
    }
    return date;
  }

  // Función EXTRA (no oficial creo) que sirve para obtener todos los días entre el rango seleccionado
  function listDays(dta, dtb) {
    var result = [];
    if (dta == undefined || dtb == undefined) {
      console.log(dta, dtb);
      return [];
    }
    var dayDiff = (dtb - dta) / 86400000;
    var d = dta.getDate();
    var n = new Date(dta.setDate(d));
    for (var i = 0; i <= dayDiff; i++) {
      n = new Date(n.setDate(d));
      d++;
      if (d > 32) {
        d = 2;
      }
      result.push($.datepicker.formatDate(dateFormat, n));
    }
    return result;
  }
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>

<label for="from">Desde </label>
<input type="text" id="from" name="from">
<label for="to"> hasta </label>
<input type="text" id="to" name="to">
```

Mi problema es que yo hasta ahora lo que he hecho para obtener la información de las fechas seleccionadas era sin necesidad de llamar al fichero `js` externo, es decir, desde mi `main.js`, obtener el valor de los `inputs` mediante `var from_datepick = $("#from").val();` y `var to_datepick = $("#to").val();`. Esto no es lo suyo, pues lo interesante sería saber llamar a la función correspondiente y obtener el valor que ella retorna.

Pero el problema es que no sé como. Si sé cargar un fichero externo pero no consigo llamar a su función, a continuación muestro una de las varias pruebas que he hecho pero esto no me retorna el resultado si no que el código tal cual entero.

```
// Código en mi main.js para acceder a la info de datepicker_range.js
$.getScript("../static/js/datepicker_range.js", function(getDate){
    console.log('JS CARGADO');
    prueba = getDate();
    console.log(prueba);
});
```

Quiero aprender a hacer esto bien ya que principalmente por ser básico, y segundo porque para obtener las fechas seleccionadas puedo hacer la trampa mencionada antes, pero tengo la otra función llamada `listDays` que si o si debo sacar su info así.

¿Como se hace correctamente para obtener el resultado de una función desde un fichero externo?

Answer (score 0):

¿Porque no referencias el archivo datepicker_range.js en tu main.js? De esa forma podrás invocar las funciones directamente, observa que esa función debe recibir el parámetro input del que saca la fecha (hace un parseo)

luego donde quieras invocar la función recuerda pasar el input con el id "from" o "to" de la fecha que quieras obtener (intenta si es posible poner un id más especifico).

Comment: Porque ni idea de cómo se hace, si me pudieras ayudarme harías un favor porque llevo días parado con esto :D

Comment: <script src="datepicker_range.js"></script>

Comment: Pon la ruta (absoluta o relativa) al archivo datepicker_range.js

Comment: https://www.lawebdelprogramador.com/foros/JavaScript/437661-src-Llamar-archivo-js-externo-y-usar-sus-funciones.html

Comment: https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/1366/c%C3%B3mo-incluir-un-archivo-javascript-a-otro-archivo-javascript-sin-utilizar-jquer